# How do I configure IIS to view GitHub flavoured MarkDown

Tags: iis, render, github-flavored-markdown

I have cloned the github repository at https://github.com/Azure/azure-content. I would like to configure an IIS site to view the content of this documentation to have a private copy

How do I configure IIS to render markdown placed in a folder on disk?

Most of the instructions have to do with setting up editors to modify the documentation or create new pages I simply want a local copy of the documentation.

Comment: One way I can think of is write http handler to convert md to html and plug it in your local application's pipeline. There are many opensource markdown converters available which you can use in your handler.

Comment: @LexLi and what is one of these?

Comment: @LexLi are you saying PankajKapare's comments are incorrect?

Comment: @LexLi how hard would it be to write one of these? Is it just an asp.net mvc app with the root directory in the web.config with a markdown converter on each page rendered?

Comment: Where you ever able to find a quick solution? IIS does not serve markdown out of the box, I usually use VS Code to preview files, but would be great if I can find an "IIS module" that makes the conversion.

Comment: No just some fleeting hope when it got a few commenters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MarkdownHttpHandler](https://github.com/orecht/MarkdownHttpHandler) is an IIS handler for markdown. Once installed all .md files will be displayed using markdown rendering js library.

See installation instructions on github.

Disclaimer: I am the author of this very modest project.

Comment: Using a phrase like `Excuse the shameless plug` is a sure-fire way to get flagged for spam. I would *highly* advise re-phrasing your answer to explain what your project does, how it relates to this question, and *how* it solves this question.

Comment: @MichaelDodd. Thanks for the comment. I am very new to StackOverlow and honestly felt the link to github would be enough to explain the purpose of the project.